# CRM 2011 - Find a record by a field's value in C#

Tags: plugins, entity, record, crm

I have a basic problem. I need to find the guid of a record with a field set to a specific value.
Like finding the only record with its "favouritecolor" attribute set to "red". (the field is unique, no double same colors)

The record I'll be searching is not of the entity type that the plug-in works on.

I've looked for this everywhere, but only found lots of tutorials about getting the Guid of a record that was just created, which doesn't help me much. Should a standard sqlconnection and select statement be used (like select guid from [table name] where favouritecolor = 'red'), or is there a more beautiful way?

I'll appreciate any kind of guidance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution at last. Hope this helps someone.
Cheers!

```
    private static Entity getTheRecord(IOrganizationService service)
    {
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.EntityName = "NameOfTheEntity";
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet() { AllColumns = true };

        query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
        query.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
        query.Criteria.Conditions.Add
        (
            new ConditionExpression("fieldname", ConditionOperator.Equal, "desiredvalue")
        );
        EntityCollection entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        return entities[0];
    }
```

Comment: Looks good, the only thing I would mention is that you should avoid using AllColumns = true on your ColumnSet when possible. That means that all the columns will be returned (even though you are not actually going to use any), so from a performance point of view you can save your self some time.

Comment: ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "wantedcolumn1", "wantedcolumn2", ... });    
Thanks for pointing that out, something like this as the columnset should work better indeed. Cheers!